# iPhone: Find Phone Number in Text

Tags: iphone

What I need is find in text Phones Numbers and make it colored and clickable and when click on that it's should call by this number...Is there on iPhone ready solution for that ? Or I should write regular expression to find phones numbers, than make it colored an clickable ? The reason I'm asking is that Android have ready method for that, and I don't need to do anything... Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put text in UITextView, there is property called dataDetectorTypes, assign it to UIDataDetectorTypeAll

Comment: Mm...that works...Thanks...when I click on phone number context menu appear...But is there any way to make call directly on click on phone number ? without context menu ?